# What is the correct way to fix this Javascript closure

Tags: javascript, closures

I have been familiarizing myself with javascript closures and ran across this article 
http://blog.morrisjohns.com/javascript_closures_for_dummies.html

Due to the closure, Example 5 does not work as expected.  How would one modify

```
result.push( function() {alert(item + ' ' + list[i])} );
```

to make the code work?

```
function buildList(list) { 
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var item = 'item' + list[i];
    result.push( function() {alert(item + ' ' + list[i])} );
  }
  return result;
}

function testList() {
  var fnlist = buildList([1,2,3]);
  // using j only to help prevent confusion - could use i
  for (var j = 0; j < fnlist.length; j++) {
    fnlist[j]();
  }
}

testList();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function buildList(list) { 
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
      var item = 'item' + list[i];
      result.push(function() {
        alert(item + ' ' + list[i]);
      });
    })(i);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Closures: If they are not solving your problem, you're just not using enough!

Answer (score 2):

You need the `i` and `item` from the different functions to be separate variables in different scopes (so they can have different values instead of being shared). Since Javascript only has function scope you need to create a wrapper function to contain these variables

```
function buildList(list) { 
  var result = [];

  function make_f(item, i){
    //item and i are now private variables of make_f
    //and wont be shared by the returned closure
    // the other variable in scope (list) is not shadowed so
    // it is still shared but that is not a problem since we
    // never change its value.
    return function() { alert(item + ' ' + list[i]) };
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var item = 'item' + list[i];
    result.push( make_f(item, i) );
  }
  return result;
}
```

You can also do the same thing with an anonymous function that is immediately invoked (the `(function(){}())` pattern).

```
function buildList(list) { 
  var result = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var item = 'item' + list[i];
    result.push( (function (item, i){
        return function(){function() {alert(item + ' ' + list[i])};
    })(item, i) );
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the first example. I find that separate helper functions often make code easier to read compared to inline anonymous functions.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in... another closure!

```
function buildList(list) { 
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    result.push((function(item, listItem){
      return function() {
        alert(item + ' ' + listItem);
      };
    })('item' + list[i], list[i]));
  }
  return result;
}

function testList() {
  var fnlist = buildList([1,2,3]);
  // using j only to help prevent confusion - could use i
  for (var j = 0; j < fnlist.length; j++) {
    fnlist[j]();
  }
}

testList();
```

Answer (score 1):

var has a function scope but if you use let then you will get block scope.

So I would do:
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) and let item...